# Files (±50MB, audio) automatically repetitively deleted (after ± a couple of hours-days?)

Tags: files

Might I ask you what can be the cause and solution of:

the automatic dissapearing of "large" files (±50MB, such as an audio file) that I have manually put into the root folder of my Drupal website/installation, using a FTP-client?

Does this has something to do with CRON (just a wild guess)? Is it not smart to manually (FTP) upload files into the root folder? Should a module be used at all times?

Comment: check you file system path on your drupal site. :) `admin/config/media/file-system`

Comment: @shrish - Thanks for the relevant reminder. There is noted `sites/default/files`by default, which is the same folder as user [skh](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/35149/skh) was referring to in the answer below.

Comment: Are you using code to integrate them with Drupal? If the managed file system thinks they are temporary it will delete them after a while.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong - Thanks, would you know how to circumvent this, i.e.: **how to make them permanent**? If I understand what you mean by *using code* as hyperlinking to them via an HTML-page or using them in a JavaScript-code; then: yes, certain drupal nodes are integrating certain of these files. --- Lastly: what exactly do you call the *managed file system*?

Comment: I meant using PHP Drupal functions from the file APIs, so they are added to the file_managed table. If they are, and their status is 0, then they get deleted after a while.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong - What do you mean by "file APIs", since I manually added these files using FTP? I was never aware of having intentionally used a PHP Drupal function. --- I have found `file_managed` via phpMyAdmin in the SQL-database, but don't know how to change the status of certain files. --- Is there any method you would now suggest, perhaps in the form of an answer? Many thanks.

Comment: You manually added them via FTP, but then how did you link them to the Drupal nodes you mention? Need more information to understand what's going on, really.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Yes indeed, I manually uploaded them. The files are actually `.mp3` audio files. They are called for using JavaScript. This JavaScript code is ± the 1 you can find in the answer of: [Clickable “positioning” hyperlinks to A/V (locally stored on your website and “hidden” behind a poster image)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095074/clickable-positioning-hyperlinks-to-a-v-locally-stored-on-your-website-and-h).

Comment: sites/default/files is intended for managed files that Drupal knows about. I am not sure what's deleting these files but if you put them in a folder of your own they should be safe.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong - I copied the files to a folder outside the Drupal directory earlier today. **Unfortunately the files there got also deleted**, later this day; simultaneous with the files at `sites/default/files`. No solution for the problem there. --- Could this perhaps be due to my website hosting?

Comment: I guess I've found the problem, since my webhost sais: "`However, we reserve a right to remove files larger than 5 MB, if some day we will start running out of disk space (this has never been done before).`" I'll try to verify this by FTP uploading a smaller file. If so, perhaps this question is not very useful here on Drupal-Stackexchange any longer, since I was just to dumb to have checked my hosting policy?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen oh, that sucks!

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong - A solution could be to put the files on a different host, like Dropbox or Google Drive. If you would have any suggestion of a good service, it would always be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not related to Drupal. The problem was a "right" (and the claim thereof) reserved by my webhost:

> However, we reserve a right to remove files larger than 5 MB, if some day we will start running out of disk space.

Perhaps this question is not very useful here on Drupal-Stackexchange any longer, since I was just too dumb to have checked my hosting policy?

---

A solution could be to put the files with a different host, like Dropbox or Google Drive. If you would have any suggestion of a good service, it would always be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this has something to do with CRON (just a wild guess)?

No, drupal won't delete files in the folder, it must be something else on your server.

> Is it not smart to manually (FTP) upload files into the root folder? Should a module be used at all times?

Files should be in your files directory (usually sites/default/files) if you're uploading them via the UI so Drupal can manage them.  If they're more static, they should be in a module/theme folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I repositioned them to `sites/default/files`; in the hope to solve the problem (30/1/2015) --- Unfortunately now (3/2/2015), I noticed the files disappeared once again (all the files I had manually put there, dissipated at once).

Comment: Is what you mean by "via the UI" using the API from the module **[File entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity)**? Should installing this (I can't figure out how to use it) solve the problem? --- I don't have any WYSIWYG text editor module installed.